# Help to verify this power supply's isolation property from its data sheet

Tags: power-supply, power

How can I tell whether [this power supply](https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/embedded-switch-mode-power-supplies-smps/7541381/)  provides any isolation by design or not, from earth ground?  (i.e. is its output floating with respect to earth ground on the AC side)

[Here](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0cdb/0900766b80cdbb06.pdf) is the only data sheet I could find.

Comment: the datasheet does not mention earth ground ... it does specify isolation voltage and isolation resistance

Answer (score 1):

> Is its output floating with respect to earth ground on the AC side?

Yes. Absolutely. These 2 specifications show that the DC output is isolated from the AC power input by these values.

> Isolation voltage (60 sec.) – Input/Output 3‘000 VAC Isolation
>   resistance – Input/Output 100 MOhm (at 500 VDC)

What they mean is that Earth ground is NOT connected to the DC outputs, therefore they are floating in the truest sense. There is no "High-impedance" connection to ground either. Many supplies have a high-impedance ground to prevent static build-up or to neutralize what few micro-amps might actually leak into the DC output side.

It is up to the design engineers and their company guidelines as to what type of Earth ground is built in, if any. This manufacture makes it clear the isolation is as good as they can make it.

[This is the link](https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/0cdb/0900766b80cdbb06.pdf) to the .pdf of this line of power supplies.

Comment: I need to connect 30 of these supplies next to each other on a board from the same mais Line and Neutral. And I need the DC sdes to be isolated from each other. Do you think in that case the isolation would be fine?

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't find any specification for isolation from "earth ground on the AC side" is because these are class 2 modules. There is no "earth ground on the AC side".

The input to output isolation voltages and DC resistance are specified, unfortunately the AC leakage from input to output doesn't seem to be.

Comment: I need to connect 30 of these supplies next to each other on a board from the same mais Line and Neutral. And I need the DC sdes to be isolated from each other. Do you think in that case the isolation would be fine?